# Power BI Web connect to MySQL database with VPN

Tags: powerbi

I have a MySQL database that will connect with power BI web, but to access the database we need to connect to a VPN first.

How can I configure power BI web to connect to the VPN and then to the database?

Do you have any solution so that we can free external bank access without power BI web VPN, such as a fixed power bi web ip?

Comment: Can you share the error, if not connected to VPN and try to access ?

Comment: Have you tried "Direct Query" functionality? which lets you connect directly from the Power BI website without using a client application to build a model.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make use of this VPN in Power BI Service. To make it possible to access your database from there, you need to install and configure [Power BI Gateway](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/gateway/) on the database server. It will allow connection to your on-premises data sources from Power BI, Power Apps and similar cloud services.